# How to read from console stream in Flutter in release app?

Tags: flutter, dart

For crash analysis reasons, I would like to read the complete console output from my release flutter-app, so that I can send it to me in case of a crash or an exception.

In my case, I have some `debugPrint(...)`s, `print(...)`s and `log(...)`s in my code, that help my in debug mode.
Is there any way to read that output when I'm in release mode?

Edit: Trying to avoid any external services, like Firebase.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics).
It will allow you to get the error when a crash occurs.

For the `debugPrint` it only print when the app is in debug mode, so there is no way to use this function to display any information on a release app.

Comment: Thanks :) but we're trying to avoid any Google services.

Comment: Btw: `debugPrint` also prints in production mode. This is a common misconception.